# Swift - Add a background image to a Spritekit scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Here's my code, i didn't use asset catalog for my image InterfaceBakground.jepg. Instead, I just dragged this 2048x1535 image to the project. But the image didn't appear the right way. I want the image to display as the background image, fill the entire screen.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "InterfaceBakground.jpeg")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.height/2, y: self.frame.width/2)

        self.addChild(background)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

I saw this on the internet which brings me a little inspiration:

> But if you’re using an image that is exactly the size of the screen,
>   it may not appear where you expect. This is because addChild adds new
>   sprites at position 0, 0 (bottom left corner) by default. If you want
>   to use an image sized specifically for your screen, you’ll have to
>   change its position.

My question is, how to change the position, so it fits devices for  different size displays? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    background.size.width = self.size.width
    background.size.height = self.size.height
    background.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5,y: 0.5)

    self.addChild(background)
}
```

AnchorPoint (0.5,0.5) which centers the image in its position.

Comment: wait,  If this works, this means your scene's anchor point is 0.5, 0.5.  That means you do not have to set anything to background  except size (all the variables here is default variable except self.size.width and self.size.height,  that will scale the sprite to the scene size)

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, but I think that you can just set the spriteNode's height and width like this. I also change the anchorPoint just to be sure:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        background.size.width = self.size.width
        background.size.height = self.size.height
        background.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)


        self.addChild(background)
    }
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't work. The image is out of the place.

Comment: no anchor point,  if his scene anchor point was at 0,0,  this would then work

Comment: You are totally right, I wasn't sure about it, just knew you could set its size like that :)